# Does the Mongosis SSIS data source work with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, ssis

I am developing an SSIS solution using Visual studio 2013. I need to read some data from a MongoDB database and write in a SQL Server database. I installed Mongosis to provide a connection manager and data source, but it doesn't appear when I open SSIS. Does the Mongosis SSIS data source work with Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: You should find it in the SSIS Toolbox, when you open the "Data Flow"-View. It's not visible under the "Control Flow".

Comment: It's not in the SSIS Toolbox when I open the Data Flow view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for using the Mongosis SSIS data source with Visual Studio 2013 was to:

1. download the Mongosis source code from Github at https://github.com/simplybusiness/mongosis
2. build the source code using Visual Studio 2013
3. Follow the instructions on the Github page to deploy the dlls

After doing this I was able to use the Mongosis SSIS data source, connection manager, and destination with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Hi, can you provide the links to the dlls required. I am not able to build the solution because of missing dlls. I need to integrate it with sql server 2014. Thanks in adv.